# Command to Sleep Display OSX

Tags: macos

Is there a command/API on OS X to put the monitor into sleep mode?

By sleep mode, I mean totally kill the output to the monitor.  I know in the power settings one can configure this but that is time based.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This can be done with a semi-undocumented api.

```
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#include <IOKit/IOKitLib.h>

/* Returns 0 on success and 1 on failure. */
int display_sleep(void)
{
    io_registry_entry_t reg = IORegistryEntryFromPath(kIOMasterPortDefault, "IOService:/IOResources/IODisplayWrangler");
    if (reg) {
                IORegistryEntrySetCFProperty(reg, CFSTR("IORequestIdle"), kCFBooleanTrue);
                IOObjectRelease(reg);
        } else {
                return 1;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

GCC Flags: `-framework CoreFoundation -framework IOKIT`

[IOKit Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/IOKitFundamentals/TheRegistry/TheRegistry.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP0000014-CGGCIHCC)

Comment: compiled version may be found here: http://www.malcolmhall.com/products/sleepdisplay/

Comment: Can you target one display in a multi-display system? This seems to sleep all displays.

Comment: regulus6633: I don't think so. This is simply requesting the OS to put the monitors to sleep. If you put one asleep then it would wake up instantly when you do something on the other. Your best bet would be to disable the second monitor in prefs->display.

Comment: I tried to create a window with a button that calls the above mentioned function but nothing happens. Any suggestions as to why this may be the case?

Comment: @David: I've updated the code to contain the header files and the gcc flags needed. I'm not sure if that will fix your problem but if not let me know.

Comment: @Tarrant: thanks that works in a non sandboxed environment. In a sandbox Lion will not allow you to set IORequestIdle.

Comment: It works also the other way around that is if you replace kCFBooleanTrue with kCFBooleanFalse you can wake up the display if it was sleeping.

Answer (score 11):

Tested in OS X 10.9.5, you can put the display to sleep with the following command:

```
$ pmset displaysleepnow
```

**Caveat**: Currently, there is a bug (small annoyance, really) in sleeping the display, in OS X 10.9.5, which I found when using a sleep display action in LaunchBar. By calling this command (action or terminal), the last pressed key is always <kbd>Return</kbd>, so this key seems to get "stuck" when you wake up the display. You'll probably never notice it but if using some sort of double modifier key tap to invoke LaunchBar, or another app (in my case, <kbd>Double Cmd</kbd>), this key combination won't work until you press <kbd>Return</kbd> again to "release" it, after waking the display.

Answer (score 9):

Programmatically, or as a user?

For the latter, Control+Shift+Eject.

Comment: Yeah looking for a programmatic solution